# How can I know a user who has finished the ratings of an App with Google Play In-App Review API?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have read the articale [Google Play In-App Review API](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review#when-to-request).

The Google Play In-App Review API lets you prompt users to submit Play Store ratings and reviews without the inconvenience of leaving your app or game, just like Code A

How can I know a user who has finished the ratings of an App with Google Play In-App Review API ?

I hope that the ratings UI will not be displayed again if a user have submitted a ratings for the App.

**Code A**

```
//val manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(mContext)
val manager = FakeReviewManager(mContext)

val request = manager.requestReviewFlow()

request.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        // We got the ReviewInfo object
        val reviewInfo = task.result

        val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(mActivity, reviewInfo)
        flow.addOnCompleteListener { _ ->
            // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
            // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
            // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
            Log.e("my","cc")
        }
        Log.e("my","bb")

    } else {
        Log.e("my","aa")
        // There was some problem, continue regardless of the result.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are worried about ratings UI will show up again if a user have already submitted a review for the App then it won't. It will not show up. However it will return a Success response as i observed . See the [Test documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test)
.

Comment: Thanks! and more, the Code A wll not always display ratings UI and Google will decide  to display or not, is it true?

Comment: Yes it is . So you always handle the error so use a fallback if you want . like showing an alert dialog to send user to play store

Comment: Thanks! How can I test Google Rating UI if the Code A can't  always display the Google ratings UI ?

Comment: And More, I run the Code A many times, it seems the  Google Rating UI never displays.

Comment: I have attached the test documentation in the answer . I must say it did not worked for me in development build . Probably u have to test it with Internal test which the documentation says.

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked it is not possible to know this as it goes against Google's policy. They clearly state that you are not allowed to give users benefits for giving reviews and as such they don't provide you with tools to know whether someone actually reviewed your app or not.

When I checked there were some shady ways of finding this out by checking the play store listing of your app (basically scraping the website), but again this is against Google's policies so you should not do this.